# how to create media query in bootstrap responsive

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have started  implementing boostrap 3.0 responsive design
  how to create media query in bootstrap  responsive, I am new in bootstrap 3, how to add responsive media query.

Comment: though i tried to edit your question.... *but* it is still **very unclear** of what u are asking!!!

Comment: bootstrap 3 is already responsive

Comment: @murugan : do you want want to add your custom `media-query` or responsive classes from bootstrap layout??? because bootstrap is already responsive!!!

Comment: yes i want to add custom media query

Comment: but right now i want advertistment adv based responsive media query

Comment: aks new question first

Comment: i want custom media query for advertisement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add meta tag on head part in  main .php

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

add css and write the code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="your_css.css">


/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/*  From Medium Devices Up To Larger Devices
 /* ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */
@media (min-width: 980px) and (max-width: 1199px) {


/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/*  Only larger Devices
 /* ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {

}

/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/*  From Small Devices Up To Medium Devices
 /* ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {

}
/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/*  Extra Small Devices Only
/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */
@media (max-width: 767px) {

}
/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/*  Extra Small Devices Only
/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    /***

}
/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/*  Up To Medium Devices
/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */
@media (max-width: 979px) {
    /***
     general body settings
     ***/


}
/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/*  Up To Medium Devices
/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */
@media (min-width: 768px) {

}
```